# How to use different controller for model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have one controller named controller1 which has bellow code to open modal dialog

```
var openDilaogBox = function () {
  $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl : 'templatepth here',
    controller  : controller2,
    keyboard    : false,
    backdrop    : false
  });
}
```

I want to use controller2 for this modal dialog. Please help.

Comment: Which library the $modal is coming from?

Comment: Just use the name of `controller2`. For example, `controller1` is `MainCtrl` and `controller2` uses `ModalCtrl`, just replace `controller2` in your code above with `ModalCtrl`. Just be sure that your `controller2` is injected properly into the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the name of `controller2`. For example, if `controller2`'s name is `ModalCtrl`, you can do it like this:

```
var openDialogBoxWithParams = function (param) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '../path/to/modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: { Param: function () { return param } }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (returnValue) {
        $scope.someData = returnValue;
    }, function () { });
};
```

Just make sure that `ModalCtrl` is injected to the app properly, i.e.

```
app.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', ...
```

Comment: Is your controller even named `ModalCtrl` or did you just copy-paste the code above?